# Handle Ctrl+Shift+A in WinForm Application

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I'm trying to capture `Ctrl+Shift+A` keydown event in an WinForm application. Here is what I've tried so far-

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift) 
{
    this.Close();
}
```

But it's not working. I've set `KeyPreview = true`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Modifiers == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift))
{
     this.Close();
}
```

Or this:

```
if (e.Control && e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
{
   this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `KeyDown` event handler:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Control && e.Shift) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think this is the simplest way.

```
if (e.Control && e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
{
   this.Close();
}
```